# How to use scipy LowLevelCallable in my own code?

Tags: python, scipy, cython

Scipy has this neat feature called LowLevelCallable: they are wrappers around compiled optimized functions (implemented in C or Cython for instance) that can be passed to numerical intensive functions that take functions as arguments. The typical example is the quadrature (numerical method to compute integrals).

My question is, how can I use this feature in my own code ?

Suppose I were to write a quadrature function myself in low-level code. Cython for instance.
How can I design it so that it may accept either a python callable as an argument or a scipy.LowLevelCallable, and get the benefits when appropriate ?

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html#faster-integration-using-low-level-callback-functions

Comment: Hi @AndrewNelson, thanks for pointing me to the scipy docs. The link you provided does not answer my question though. It is an example of defining a LowLevelCallable and passing it to scipy's own quadrature function. I'd like to know how I can replicate the inner workings of quadrature in my own code so that I can accept both regular Python functions and LowLevelCallables.

Comment: In that case you'll need to look at the scipy codebase to understand how scipy does it. It won't be a simple task probably.

Comment: I don't think the quadrature function *is* written in low level code. The source code is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.2/scipy/integrate/_quadrature.py#L291-L373 Looks like regular Python to me. In that case, you could match scipy's performance without writing low level code either.

Comment: Some parts are. cf https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h for instance.
I've actually succeded in doing what I wanted to do, and the result can be found at https://github.com/gabrielfougeron/choreo/tree/main/choreo/scipy_plus/cython . I don't feel very confident in writing up an answer with my findings though, because it might not be the best way of doing it. I've initiated a discussion thread with the scipy team to investigate the issue though, see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19148